# What icon(s) would represent different timeframes in a dashboard widget?

Tags: icon, interface-design

I'm working on a KPI application where basically I need to display the overtime trend of some indicators, for simplicity's sake let's assume the indicator is the number of visitors a web page has over time. I currently display the value and if it is increasing (positive) or decreasing (negative) compared to the previous period. From the same element I need to be able to switch timeframe (day, month or year) and this is where I'm stuck right now. I'd like to use icons for selecting the timeframe and adding a column on my element (something like this https://dribbble.com/shots/1129568-Los-Angeles-CA  -  see left column) but I can't come up with icons that easily differentiate day, month, and year.

How do you guys suggest me to tackle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Hello VIncent. No, at this point I haven't tried any icons yet since nothing comes to mind when I think about possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifically looking for day/month/year, try looking at what some calendar applications use to see what type of visual language has already been established and works well.

This type of thing shows up when I googled "Calendar icons":

[image: calendar icon examples]

On the other hand, Google Calendar uses text ("Day" "Week" "Month" etc), which is something to consider.